# How to have different api urls for staging and production in Swift and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I'm building an app that accesses an API that lives on our servers. So obviously there will be a different url for the staging server, vs the live app (that lives int the app store) which will point to the production server api url. What's the best/easiest way to accomplish that in Swift using Xcode 6? And then how do you go about accessing those urls in your controllers/app?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497552/how-to-configure-independent-sets-of-runtime-settings-in-xcode

Comment: I saw that, but it's 3+ years old...I didn't know if that was still applicable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was Swift specific...I found it at the following link. It can be accomplished using Swift custom compiler flags and Schemes.

http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/build-configuration-management-with-swift/

Comment: Or you can just put it into a .plist and read it from disk at runtime. Same code, different data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difference between the staging URLs and the live URLs should be the base URLs.

So you need to implement your APIs in a way so that every time you hit an API, you pick the base url from a common place and append the particular end point for that API to the base url and continue with the request.

In that way, changing the base URL only is going to help you achieve this.

Comment: Right, this isn't what I was referring to. The API will obviously be the same except for the base urls...being able to store both base urls and have them switch based on the state of the app (whether it's a live app in the app store or being tested in xcode/test device) is what I was referring to. That way I only have to flip a switch of some kind and not do a find/replace.

Comment: I am not able to understand the point you are making,
Cause before submitting the build to appStore,you can always change your base url and submit it.

And while in development stage, you can always switch back to the dev URL.