# Have two GoogleService-Info.plist in one target in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, target, environment

I have two different environments setup in on target (one for development and another for production), because of that i want to use two different GoogleService-Info.plist but still without success. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: maybe use different targets ?

Comment: @Shubhank what can i do with two targets?

Comment: 2 Files with same name can't be added to same target. but if you have multiple target - you can add each one to a separate target.

Comment: @Shubhank so... and with one target?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497552/how-to-configure-independent-sets-of-runtime-settings-in-xcode for more discussion about the options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the following solution:

Create a GoogleService-CONFIGURATION-Info.plist file for every XCode configuration. Don't link the files to a target.

Add a Run Script Build Phase:

`cp ${SRCROOT}/Resources/Firebase/GoogleService-${CONFIGURATION}-Info.plist ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/GoogleService-Info.plist`

Comment: Firebase unable to find the file

Comment: That is the solution! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

1. keep the same names for both GoogleService-Info.plist
2. put one GoogleService-Info.plist inside a subfolder, say "development"
3. add references to both files in Xcode, while link them to corresponding targets
4. just use FIRApp.configure() in your AppDelegate, done